# Not able to get file path when using GoogleDrive in android version 4.4.2

Tags: android, image, file

In my android application, i have used google drive to pick images and files to my application, it works perfectly in all API version except 4.4.2, whenever i tried to pick image or file i can get the file name but not able to get file path, it always returns empty path

My code :

```
   // Get real path from Google Drive
        public String getPathfromGoogleDrive(Intent data, Uri contentURI) {

            if (contentURI == null) {
                return null;
            }
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            String mCurrentPhotoPath = new String();

            Cursor cursor = null;

            int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            LogUtil.d("currentapiVersion" + currentapiVersion);

            if (currentapiVersion == 19) {

                String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(contentURI);

                // Split at colon, use second item in the array
                String id = wholeID.split(";")[0];

                // where id is equal to
                String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

                cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        filePathColumn, sel, new String[] { id }, null);

                LogUtil.d("Cursor Count" + cursor.getCount());

                if (cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    mCurrentPhotoPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                }

            }
```

My Intent :

```
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        if (currentapiVersion == 19) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            String strType = "*/*";
            intent.setDataAndType(null, strType);
            startActivityForResult(intent, Gallery);

        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
            String strType = "*/*";
            intent.setDataAndType(null, strType);
            startActivityForResult(intent, Gallery);
        }
```

Please correct me if i have did any mistake
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting file real path, we can use input stream as like below

```
  Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input =  getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageURI);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

To Get File from drive and write that into locale(sd card)

```
sourceuri - your cnontent uri
destination - path where you want to save in sd card
public boolean savefile(String name, Uri sourceuri, String destination)
            throws IOException {
        // String sourceFilename = sourceuri.getPath();

        int originalsize = 0;
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(sourceuri);

            Log.Logger().finest("input in profileview Activity" + input);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            filenotfoundexecption = true;

        }

        try {
            originalsize = input.available();

            Log.Logger().finest(
                    "Profile view activity originalsize" + originalsize);

            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try {
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                        destination, false));
                byte[] buf = new byte[originalsize];
                bis.read(buf);
                do {
                    bos.write(buf);
                } while (bis.read(buf) != -1);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Mint.logException(e);

                filenotfoundexecption = true;

                return false;

            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
            Mint.logException(e1);
            filenotfoundexecption = true;
        }

        /*
         * String[] cmd = new String[] { "logcat", "-f", GridViewDemo_LOGPATH,
         * "-v", "time", "ActivityManager:W", "myapp:D" };
         * 
         * Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
         */

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I want to get file from google drive path. How i can achieve it ?

Comment: @AnandSavjani did you got content URI when pick file from drive?

Comment: i get content URI but how to get file from drive ? Please suggest for it

Comment: Ok if you want to get your file and write that into your locale then check it out my updated answer